# Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: n is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, error-handling

I found a lot of article about this error, but looks like every case is special so I coudn't fine my answer.

So my code should work like:

1. Find a special field in a List (ID:101 this is a unique number in the column so only 1 field is targeted).
2. Get the number from it.
3. Update that number to number+1

But instead of it I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: n is not a function" and the details target the jquery.min.js and sharepointplus.min.js. (I can't be sure but probably the sharepointplus based part of the code is working fine cause I could upgrade severel fields in my other codes)

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
  var ID=101;
  $SP().list("INNList", "http://.../sites/Registry/").get(
  {
    fields: "n1k8"
  },
  {
    where: 'INNnumber = '+Number(ID)
  }, alert("step1: "+Number(szam)),  //this alerts works
  function getData(info) //probably something wrong around here (alerts not works after this part)
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
    {
      $SP().list("INNList", "http://.../sites/Registry/").update(
      {
        n1k8: (Number(info[i].getAttribute("n1k8")) + Number("1"))
      },
      {
        where: 'INNnumber = '+Number(ID)
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I started javascript just recently so it can be even a trivial mistake. Thanks you very much for you suggestions!

Comment: it might be the order you reference those js files, not your code.

Comment: referencing the same js file more than once can also cause issues

Comment: My order is: 1. jquery.min.js, 2. jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js, 3. sharepointplus-4.0.min.js. And I have only 1 reference in my script. I tryed to change the order, but looks like I get the same error. But thanks you very much for the idea! If u have other suggestions let me know.

Comment: If you are using $ for sharepointplus (or any other 3rd party) then you cannot use the $ shorthand for jQuery

Answer (score 1):

if you are using shorthand "$" for sharepointplus (or any other 3rd party) then you cannot use "$" for jQuery.

Try replacing "$" with "jQuery"

example: 
replace: $(document) 
with: jQuery(document)

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea! I changed the  $(document) with: jQuery(document), but still getting the same error :( Also I have other codes in my program where I use $ for both document and sharepointplus, but working well So probably something else. If u have any other suggestion let me know and I ll test it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: what is the order of your referenced JS files?